# php: Unable to return to my site after Paypal payment

Tags: php, paypal

First I created test accounts for sandbox which were generated as following by Paypal:

1- me@mail.com
2- me-facilitator@mail.com
2- me-buyer@mail.com

Now I turned Auto Return to ON on my MAIN account I am using for Paypal that is `me@mail.com`. My form looks like:

```
<form action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' id="frmPayPal" name='frmPayPal'>
            <input type='hidden' name='business' value='me-facilitator@mail.com'>
            <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>

            <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Awesome Stuff'>
            <input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='0002'>
            <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='0.99'>
            <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
            <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
            <input type='hidden' name='handling' value='0'>
            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
            <input type='hidden' name='return_method' value='2' />
            <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://296c6e7b.ngrok.io/clients/ryan/pay.php'>
            <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://296c6e7b.ngrok.io/clients/ryan/pay.php'>
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
        </form>
```

Now I can make successful purchase but it does not return to the URL.

I am submitting form via jQuery

Comment: Are there no AUTO RETURN settings for me-facilitator@mail.com?

Comment: I did, no changed.. still just show receipt that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login your `me-facilitator@mail.com` and enable the `Auto Return for Website Payments` just like how you did in your me@mail.com.

How i figured it out? because of this:

`<input type='hidden' name='business' value='me-facilitator@mail.com'>`

Comment: Login to make payment?

Comment: no, you need to login the account and change its settings in My Account Overview Profile -> My Selling Tools -> Website Preferences. the auto return on you set was on `me@mail.com`, so logout that account and login `me-facilitator@mail.com` and set the auto return true

Comment: Well I set the original account here but still no difference. Check here http://296c6e7b.ngrok.io/clients/ryan/pix.php - Click on Grid#4

Comment: try to Turn off PayPal Account Optional setting, if still does not work then manually add the return url in the  `Auto Return URL` setting, make sure you are logged in your sandbox paypal account as `me-facilitator@mail.com`.

Comment: Ok I logged in. There is no SELLING TOOLS options in test account which means I can't set return URL in a test account

Comment: You can change its password in `https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/`.

Comment: I logged in. You cant set return URLs in test accounts.

Comment: Logged in here: `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin/` using the me-facilitator@mail.com, then go to Profile -> My Selling Tools , you should be seeing this, i did this again just now to double check.

Comment: This is my facilitator account I created, and i can open the settings [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwGXfcQLgYR0M1NQWlJMRE9id0k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Should I give you my credentials of facilitator or main account?

Comment: No, not thats not necessary, we can move this discussion to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114453/discussion-between-efx-and-volatil3).